# Remove hover menu on category click

Tags: wordpress, menu, categories

I have a WordPress website and I use the Woodmart theme. When I click on a category, the menu is transformed into a hover menu and I want to remove this. Is it possible? I want to be every time like in the picture, not with hover.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info to get a suitable answer, please explain how you want the categories to be listed.

other than that, you can always go to the "**Customize**" section (located on the page header).

[image]

A sidebar editor appears on the left, from there you can go to "**Header**"

[image]

Then scroll down till you see "**Header Main**"

[image]

from there you can customize your pages' categories and other stuff as well like the header of your page.